# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SocketRasp: (?)

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, error-handling, socket.io

> Hi everyone !!

I've this error, and I don't find why ....

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SocketRasp: (?).
>       at syntaxError (http: //localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:80840:34)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http: //localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:94915:35)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http: //localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:94783:26)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (http: //localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:94769:21)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http: //localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:95060:40)
>       at http: //localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:94989:49
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http: //localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:94949:19)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http: //localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:94604:50)
>       at JitCompiler._loadModules (http: //localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:105945:70)

The problem come with this file:

```
import { NgModule, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

@Injectable()
export class SocketRasp extends Socket
{
    ipAddress: String;
    constructor(ipAddress: String)
    {
       super({ url: 'http://'+ ipAddress + ':8080', options: {} }); //Port can be placed in ipAddress, think to delete it, in that case
    }

//getters

//setters

//methods
}
```

I've the same problem on other file but it's not really important !

and the package.json is:

```
{
"name": "io.cordova.myapp6ab750",
"author": "",
"homepage": "",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
 "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
 "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
 "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
 "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
 "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "4.3.5",
  "@angular/compiler": "4.3.5",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.5",
  "@angular/core": "4.3.5",
  "@angular/forms": "4.3.5",
  "@angular/http": "4.3.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.5",
  "@ionic-native/core": "4.1.0",
  "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.1.0",
  "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.1.0",
  "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
  "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
  "ionicons": "3.0.0",
  "rxjs": "5.4.3",
  "socket.io": "^2.0.4",
  "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
  "zone.js": "0.8.16"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
  "typescript": "2.3.4"
 },
"description": "Ionic2Blank: An Ionic project",
"cordovaPlugins": [
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
  "cordova-plugin-console",
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
  "cordova-plugin-device",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
  "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"-vs-binding": {
  "BeforeBuild": [
  "ionic:build"
  ]
 }
}
```

and the app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SocketIoModule } from 'ngx-socket-io';
//pages
import { viewerPage } from '../pages/viewer/viewer';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { SocketRasp } from '../assets/typescript/SocketRasp';


@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   MyApp,
    HomePage,
    viewerPage
  ],
imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  HttpClientModule,
  BrowserModule,
  SocketIoModule
 ],
 bootstrap: [IonicApp],
 entryComponents: [
  MyApp,
   HomePage,
   viewerPage
 ],
 providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    SocketRasp]
 //{ provide: "_IP_ADDRESS_", useValue: "169.254.25.25" /*your ip address*/ },
})
 export class AppModule {}
```

I read some update can helped, but which one ?? or something else !

Comment: its probably because you are trying to inject a string in the provider `constructor(ipAddress: String)`.. is that a custom provider or in the library?

Comment: i update the post with the file of the provider

Comment: ngx-socket-io which is imported in SocketRasp is a library from npm, it works on two parameters url and options, and i want to change a part of the url myself, with the constructor for example, and you have to put something in your provider it's what i did